# Call single function twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a mysql function `function1(n AS varchar)` which returns some comma seperated string like `str1, str2`.

I can fire a select statement like

```
Select function1("ABC") from dual;
```

I want to insert output of this function in a table like `comlumn1` contains `str1` and `column2` contains `str2` I can do it with call `function1("ABC")` 2 times and split output by comma and store each part in particular column. but is there any way to insert values to table by just calling `function1` only once.

Comment: Not really. you could do `select @x := function1("ABC")`, then use the `@x` variable wherever you need. but you cannot have a single function call return data to two different places in a query string. That's not possible in pretty much any language.

Comment: @MarcB It is possible in MySQL due to the magic of `JOIN`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
   UPDATE table_name t
     JOIN (
       SELECT function1("ABC") val
/*       FROM dual /* Not sure if you need this */
          ) f
      SET t.column1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.val,', ', 1),
          t.column2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.val,', ',-1)
/*  WHERE ... */
```

I'm pretty sure that'll only call the function once.

Comment: That `FROM dual` part is only to be a bit more compatible to Oracle. In Oracle's `SELECT` syntax is the keyword `FROM` not optional.

Comment: @VMai it is necessary in some MySQL, if you want a WHERE clause for example.. you are right however, it probably isn't necessary here.